# SMSBroadCast, How do I receive and output SMS I have sent?

Tags: android-studio, sms, broadcast

I have this snippet to receive incoming text messages and show them as a notification with Toast and stick the containing Senders Phone and Message body inside a file with writeToFile();. How do I receive text messages I send to others ?

```
public class SMSBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

        private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
        private static final String TAG = "SMSBroadcastReceiver";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Intent recieved: " + intent.getAction());
            Toast.makeText(context, "Recieved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if (SMS_RECEIVED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                if (bundle != null) {
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
                    final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                        messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                    }
                    if (messages.length > -1) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Message recieved: " + messages[0].getMessageBody());
                        Toast.makeText(context, messages[0].getDisplayOriginatingAddress(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        try {
                            writeToFile( messages[0].getDisplayOriginatingAddress()+messages[0].getMessageBody());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(context,e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was as easy as using Uri to get the content from my "Sent" box.

```
 TextView view = new TextView(this);
    Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null,null);
    String sms = "";
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        sms += "To :" + cur.getString(2) + " : " + cur.getString(12)+"\n";
    }
   //Do code with string (sms)
```